# Does standalone LaTeX exist?

Tags: installing, windows

Is there a standalone version of LaTeX that might run of, say, a USB stick? So a version that doesn't need installing. I am looking for something to run under Windows.

Comment: This has already been posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233402/does-standalone-latex-exist (which you might think should be migrated to an appropriate site rather than reposted).

Comment: @N.N Yes, sorry about that. I didn't know that you could migrate like that. I will do that next time this happens.

Comment: If you want a tiny file, you can use mathjax(http://www.mathjax.org/), with this file (http://jsfiddle.net/Zky72/2/). But you shall need an internet connection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update 2014-02**: It has been two years since this response was written. As of February 2014, available packages for USB installation are: [TexLive option to run from USB stick](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) (for multiple OSes), [MikTex Portable](http://miktex.org/portable), and [TexPortable](https://symera.de/texportable) (both Windows).

**Original response:**

<strike>I guess you're looking for USBTeX: http://www.exomatik.net/U-Latex/USBTeXEnglish</strike>

*Update 2014-02*: USBTeX seems to be no longer maintained; the above URL does not work anymore.

Comment: It looks as if this is a `windoze` only solution.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Of course, since the OP explicitly asked for it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I just wanted to add the comment because some answers are for multiple platforms.

Comment: OK. I didn't think about that. Good point :)

Comment: @symera: Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated this answer 2 years after to include the current status.

Answer (score 32):

[TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) has options for running from a [USB stick](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable).

Comment: This solution is for multiple OSs.

Answer (score 11):

[MikTex Portable](http://miktex.org/portable) is exactly what you want. It is a "portable" version of MiKTeX, one of the major TeX distributions, by the MiKTeX project itself. It's the first thing to try before considering repackaged distributions.

Comment: It would be great if the answer would contain more than just a link, such as a short information what MiKTeX Portable offers. An edit would be nice, for future readers.

Answer (score 8):

USBTeX is no longer maintained and the link (http://www.exomatik.net/U-Latex/USBTeXEnglish) is broken, so if you still are looking for a portable LaTeX environment for Windows, you could try TexPortable, which you can obtain from [here](https://symera.de/texportable).

Basically it's a combination of MiKTeX, Texmaker and SumatraPDF.

If you're going to give it a try, please let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 4):

The [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) DVD has `LaTeX(TeXLive distro)`, `Kile`,`TeXmaker` and even `Lyx` basically  pre-installed.  It will run in [VMWare](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=linuxDevijverVMWare2&fromSeriesID=38), [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), or any other virtualization software. You can download the [ISO image](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html). Be advised this is an entire operating system, which runs from the DVD. You can boot into it outright, or just run it in a Virtual Machine. Order CD/DVD [online](http://www.osdisc.com/) and other [KNOPPIX vendors](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-vendors/index-en.php) in addition to vendors at [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/) can send you a DVD for cheap

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to the software?

Comment: You can download the ISO image http://knoppix.net/get.php.  Be advised this is an entire operating system, which runs from the DVD.   You can boot into it outright, or just run it in a Virtual Machine.   OSDisc.org and other vendors (linked to on distrowatch.com) can send you a DVD for cheap.