# Configuration of Texmaker to work with MiKTeX Portable

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows

I have MiKTeX Portable on my USB, and I've installed Texmaker on my machine with Windows XP.

I cannot find a way to configure Texmaker so that it compiles with MiKTeX portable. It just prompts me with the message "Could not start the command."

I guess that I should configure that in `Option -> Configure Texmaker -> Quick Build`. 
But I don't know what to do there.

I've done research and could not find solution. I find one [workaround](http://jimstitzel.com/2010/01/configuring-texmaker-usb-with-miktex-portable/) where they use Texmaker USB with MiKTeX Portable, but it's not I want (and it's quite complicated).

Any advice and help would be appreciated. Or if you know some other LaTeX editor that can be easily configured for MiKTeX Portable. The built in editor TeXworks works just fine, but I would love to have a more user friendly interface.

### Edit

I use the following versions: Texmaker 4.1 and MiKTeX is 2.9.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have MikTeX installed on your USB stick, but TeXmaker installed on your PC? Is MikTeX not installed on your PC?

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, that is the case. And no, MikTex is not installed on my PC.

Comment: Hence this other question: what's the point of having an IDE  (TeXmaker in your case) installed on a machine without any TeX distribution? Wouldn't it be simpler to have *both* IDE *and* TeX distro on the USB stick (and/or on your machine)?

Comment: I cannot install MiKTeX on my machine, it prompts me with an error (unknown reasons). So I thought that this would be the simplest solution, but as I see that apparently it is not. So, what do you think, if I follow steps in tutorial that I gave link to in question, should that work? Or if you know simpler solution. Thank you for help.

Comment: I just read the comments on the tutorial, and it is not applicable for these latest versions.

Comment: Try to solve the real issue (if necessary, in an own question): What is the error message, when you want to install MiKTeX on your system? Don’t you perhaps have the user right for installation?

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem. I've found two ways to make it work:

**Solution 1. Add miktex portable to the environment variable `PATH`.**

Even if you don't have administrative privileges on the machine, you can usually set the variable just for your account. I wouldn't use it while keeping miktex on a USB drive but if you copied it onto the disk it should be alright.

1. Go the folder with miktex and find the subfolder `miktex\bin`. Copy
   its full path (`C:\...\miktex\bin`).
2. Go to the Start menu, type *variable*, select *Edit environment variables for your account*.
3. On the upper list find `PATH` and double-click it. Add a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the text in the box and after that paste the previously copied path. Close everything with OKs. If you relaunch TexMaker, it should work now. *Sometimes you need to log out of your Windows account and log back in, or restart your computer, before it works.*

**Solution 2. Launch TexMaker from within Miktex.**

This solution has the benefit of not changing anything in the computer settings but it's not permanent - you need to do this every time you start TexMaker.

1. Launch Miktex portable - double click the `miktex-portable` file.
2. An icon appered in the system tray, next to the clock. Right-click it and select *Command Prompt*.
3. Navigate to the folder with TexMaker using `cd` command (e.g. by typing `cd C:\...\texmakerwin32usb`, wherever you put it). Launch TexMaker by typing `texmaker`. It should be able to compile tex files now.

Comment: To your solution 1: The OP has a real portable MiKTeX on USB drive, so this is not well applicable. Your solution 2 is what I wrote in my answer with a bit more explanation (but nethertheless in my opinion yours is better written).

Comment: I found Solution 2 here very helpful. Didn't occur to me to make use of the prompt.

Comment: **Solution 1:** 2. My upper list does not have PATH, it has TEMP and TMP only. What should I do to make my Texmaker understand to use Texlive to compile my tex file? Now my Texmaker is using Miktex.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a little bit late but I made a portable collection of a LaTeX environment for Windows systems. Now, I finally found the time to publish it. So hopefully [TexPortable](https://github.com/symera/TexPortable#texportable) could help you.
If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You could go through [Recently Active 'texmaker miktex' Questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texmaker+miktex) and look, whether your bundle could help, and add a note there, but then as Community Wiki, otherwise perhaps the admins get angry. ;-)

Comment: I've to admit that there are so much questions about this issue it would probably look or feel like spamming if I would add a note under each question. Think I should wait a while...

Comment: Like @Speravir suggested, If you wish, `TexPortable` can be replaced instead of broken url http://www.exomatik.net/U-Latex/USBTeXEnglish atleast in widely viewed portable usb tex Q's [Does standalone LaTeX exist?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44139/15717) and [texmaker 3.5 miktex portable 2.9 and epstopdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69040/15717)

Answer (score 1):

In this configuration, as you have it now, there is no cure.

You cannot use the commands from inside of TeXmaker, you must work on command line, but only with the Command Prompt you get from the tray icon of MiKTeX portable! The reason is the system path:
Start a command prompt from your system <sup><sub>(e.g. press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd` in the input line)</sub></sup> and type `echo %path%`. Do the same again in the command prompt started from MiKTeX portable. Confer the first entry.