# epstopdf misspelled or could not be found

Tags: epstopdf

I have a problem compiling eps-files with the epstopdf package. I use TeXStudio portable and try to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{test.eps}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code gives me the error "epstopdf" either misspelled or does not exist. So I tried to convert the eps-file prompt and get the same error message.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my Latex setup?

Thank you!

Comment: Sound as if you don't have the epstopdf executable. Which texsystem do you have?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with "texsystem"?

Comment: @Froop: What kind of LaTeX installation do you have? Are you working on Windows, on a Mac or on Linux?

Comment: I'm working with Miktex portable on Windows.

Comment: @Froop: You have installed MiKTeX packages `miktex-ghostscript-base`, `miktex-ghostscript-bin`, `miktex-graphics-bin`?

Comment: I can find miktex-ghostscript-base, but the other packages are missing. I will try to install them!

Comment: I can not find any of these packages. But I tried to run epstopdf.exe on cmd and it worked, when I wrote the exact path. Without the path I got the same error as latex gives me. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

So finaly I found a solution for the problem.

`Solution 2. Launch TexMaker from within Miktex` from the link [Configuration of Texmaker to work with MiKTeX Portable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145465/configuration-of-texmaker-to-work-with-miktex-portable) worked. I followed the description and opened texstudio via miktex. After I did this I could compile eps-files without any errors. Now I can open texstudio without starting miktex previously and it still works with eps-files.