# How to set PATH variable in portable miktex to be used with texmaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker, paths, environment-variables

When I perform `ps->pdf` or `XeLaTeX` I get error

```
'mgs.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The solution for this is to add `...\miktexport\miktex\bin` to the `PATH` variable, because `mgs.exe` exist in this folder.

I did this and now I have no problems to compile my document via command line.

However I would like to call `XeLaTeX` via `TexMaker` shortcut but in this case I still get that mgs is not recognized. I guess that this is because portable miktex has its own `PATH` variable, which is different from system `PATH` variable

So I still cannot call XeLaTeX from portable TexMaker, since mgs.exe is still not recognized. In TeXMaker configuration I have the following command for XeLaTeX

```
"../miktexport/miktex/bin/xelatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Any solution?

Comment: Go to the command line and check if you are able to run xelatex from there. Also, check that the path given to xelatex is correct. The "../" indicate that the command is run from the parent directory of "miktexport". If that not correct, the command will fail. Since the .exe file is in the path, you may try to remove the path from the configuration file, i.e. use `"xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"`.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The solution is to insert appropriate mikex/bin path in TexMaker via `Configure Texmaker->Add To PATH` option, but then you `MUST RESTART` TexMaker, otherwise the changes in PATH variable will not be made.  I spend whole day on this problem, and next day when I open program again everything was worked.

Comment: See also [Configuration of Texmaker to work with MiKTeX Portable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145465/configuration-of-texmaker-to-work-with-miktex-portable).