# How to add PDFtoSVG to path in order to use writetex in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

The goal is to use LateX equations within Inkscape. I would like to utilize **writetex**. On its [site](https://writetex.tk/), under *installation*, it is written to:

> Make sure you have at least one LaTeX command and one PDFtoSVG
>   converter are in your path.

As far as LaTex path is concerned, I made sure that I have the entry within path system variable according to kamilk's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145465/configuration-of-texmaker-to-work-with-miktex-portable).
I would like to know how to add this PDFtoSVG to path with least possible effort. I found an [application](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/), which requires additional installations and looks to work only on Linux.

Can you show me the most straightforward way to make everything work:
which PDFtoSVG program should I download and how to correctly add it to the path?

I have Inkscape 0.92, Mitex package and Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I found the following solution.

It's been a while since the  original post and there may have already been found a solution, but I'll answer because it could help someone looking for the same issue.

First, I assume that one has already downloaded `pdf2svg` for Windows from this link: https://github.com/jalios/pdf2svg-windows (green button `[Clone or Download] > Download Zip`)

Extract it, choose the 32bit or 64bit folder according to the system and copy it for example, in `C:\Program Files\pdf2svg`. 
Now, a new environment variable must be set as follows:

`Control Panel > Advanced system settings > [Environment Variables...]`

In `User-Variables-for-<username>`, click on `PATH` and `[Edit...]`, click on `[New]`, then `[Browse...]`, find and `Add the previous directory C:\Program Files\pdf2svg`. Then finally accept everything. 
 Now it should work!

This page explains everything in Spanish: https://medium.com/@01luisrene/como-agregar-variables-de-entorno-so-windows-10-e7f38851f11f